# How to use CSS to modify a font?

Tags: css, fonts, webfonts, google-fonts

Previously we used the font  ['World of Water'](http://typodermicfonts.com/world-of-water/) which supports this symbol: 
https://codepen.io/jaygray/pen/gvLYmW

```
<img src='/static/image/onto_symb_w421_h421.png'>
```

Now we would like to use a web font and have found one similar to 'World of Water' - Convergence (https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Convergence)

How to construct the character on the above Codepen in CSS?

Here are two attempts.

First: outlined white on a dark blue background:
https://codepen.io/jaygray/pen/eVdqbj

Second: outlined white on a light blue background:
https://codepen.io/jaygray/pen/rJMXPZ

The problems with #1 and #2 are that the lower bar is too wide and does not have the outline.

**How to slightly reduce the width of the lower bar, add an outline to the bar, and center the bar under the letter 'o'?**

(note: lower bar in #2 is blue so it is easier to see. it should be white with blue outline.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use pseudo-elements to create a new element, which you can modify all you want:

```
.onto::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: .1em;
  top: 100%;
  right: .1em;
  bottom: -.1em;
  background-color: white;
  outline: 1px solid #0379C4;
}
```

- Blue: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/zRoKoR
- Light: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/NybRNx

And if you want the character to remain at the same level, you need to use:

```
transform: scale(.8);
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/LQbRxg